# Error while setting the color of a cell

Tags: python, python-2.7, openpyxl

I'm trying to use openpyxl to set the color of cell, however I'm getting:

> AttributeError: type object 'Color' has no attribute 'DARKYELLO

This is the code:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.styles import Font, Style
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.writer.styles import StyleWriter
from openpyxl.styles import  Border, Color, Font
# ...
self.bworkSheet["A" + str(self.indexLine)].style.fill.start_color = Color.DARKYELLOW
self.bworkSheet["A" + str(self.indexLine)].value = "Duplicate Photo"
```

Comment: Browsing the documentation, I think color constants are in `colors`, not `Color`.

Comment: still got error: 
NameError: global name 'colors' is not defined

Comment: did you import it first?

Comment: do you import colors? in addition to color?

Comment: now I got a diffrent error:
line 53, in __setattr__
    raise TypeError('cannot set %s attribute' % name)
TypeError: cannot set start_color attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Styles are immutable and cannot be changed once they've been created.